# Create a SELECT with defined number of rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that should insert some random rows in a table depending on the `amount` values

```
@amount1 INT --EligibilityID = 1
@amount2 INT --EligibilityID = 2
@amount3 INT --EligibilityID = 3
```

Maybe the obvious way is to use `TOP(@amount)` but there are a lot of amount values and the second select is much larger. So, I was looking for a way to do it in a single statement if possible.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CaseInfo]
  SELECT ([EligibilityID],[CaseNumber],[CaseMonth])
  FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@amount1) [EligibilityID],[CaseNumber],[CaseMonth]
    FROM [dbo].[tempCases]
    WHERE [EligibilityID] = 1
  )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CaseInfo]
  SELECT ([EligibilityID],[CaseNumber],[CaseMonth])
  FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@amount2) [EligibilityID],[CaseNumber],[CaseMonth]
    FROM [dbo].[tempCases]
    WHERE [EligibilityID] = 2
  )

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CaseInfo]
  SELECT ([EligibilityID],[CaseNumber],[CaseMonth])
  FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@amount3) [EligibilityID],[CaseNumber],[CaseMonth]
    FROM [dbo].[tempCases]
    WHERE [EligibilityID] = 3
  )
```

Comment: SQL "good practice" is to always list the columns in an insert statement.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. How many rows do you want inserted? @amount1? @amount2? @amount1 * @amount2?

Comment: I want to insert \@amount1 rows in CaseInfo where EligibilityID=1, \@amount2 rows where EligibilityID=2, and so on. The statement that I wrote was what I thought at first aproach but it would repeat as many times as number of amounts in the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use row_number, partitioned by eligibilityID, and then compare it with a case statement to select the correct variable each time:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CaseInfo]
  SELECT ([EligibilityID],[CaseNumber],[CaseMonth])
  FROM (
    SELECT [EligibilityID],[CaseNumber],[CaseMonth]
           ,row_number() over (partition by EligibilityID order by CaseNumber) as rn -- you haven't mentioned an ORDER BY, you can change it here
    FROM [dbo].[tempCases]
  ) as table1
  where rn<=case
                when EligibilityID=1 then @amount1
                when EligibilityID=2 then @amount2
                when EligibilityID=3 then @amount3
            end
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this is what i wanted, thanks.